# How can I add resources to tauri app post build

Tags: tauri

I'm looking to add resources to my app dynamically.

My workflow is like this:

- Build and deploy app
- Install locally
- Add files to the Resources directory
- Serve those files from the app

The files I'm loading are actually zip files which contain some html which I will serve via an iframe

To start with I will be adding the zip manually but the end goal is to download them whilst using the app and they get stored in a kind of offline mode (like downloading a netflix movie for watching offline).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [File System API](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs) to store/retrieve files from the system. You'll also need [HTTP API](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/http) to make API calls to the server (to download files). Make sure to enable those APIs in the `tauri.conf.json`.

Official docs provide plenty of examples:

```
import { readTextFile, BaseDirectory } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';
// Read the text file in the `$APPDATA/my_data.txt` path
const contents = await readTextFile('my_data.txt', { dir: BaseDirectory.AppData });
```

To add resources manually ("inject", for testing only), first, you'll need to find where app files are being stored. For this, you can use [Path API](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/path).

Example:

```
import {appDataDir} from "@tauri-apps/api/path";
// On windows prints C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\your-app-name
console.log(await appDataDir());
```

Store your files in the `appDataDir`, then you should be able to read them as shown in the first example.

This is how your `allowlist` in the `tauri.conf.json` can look like:

```
"allowlist": {
  "http": {
    "all": true,
    "scope": ["https://api.samplesite.com/*"]
  },
  "path": {
    "all": true
  },
  "fs": {
    "all": true,
    "scope": ["$APPDATA/*"]
  }
}
```